# a4j:commandButton oncomplete javascript ignored

Tags: javascript, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have this snippet:

> ```
>   <h:form>
>         <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="modalYesNo">
>             <a4j:region id="confirmActionReloadYes">
>                 <a4j:commandButton value="Yes" ajaxSingle="true"
>                     action="#{MyBacking.reloadConfig}"
>                     oncomplete="window.location.reload()"
>                     reRender="blah" />
>             </a4j:region>
>             <a4j:commandButton value="No"
>                 onclick="#{rich:component('confirmActionReload')}.hide();return false;" />
>         </h:panelGrid>
>     </h:form>
> ```

and I notice that when the yes button in the a4j:region above is selected, once the backing bean method `reloadCongi()` is complete, the javascript `window.location.reload()` is not run.  Why is this?  I also notice that elements in the reRender attribute are also not reRendered.  Why is this?

*EDIT*
The method from the first comment to this question is:

```
public void reloadConfig() {
    logger.info("Reloading config.");
    pct = pctBackup;
    feeds = pct.getFeed();
    setSysMsg("Reloaded config OK.", "ok");
}
```

I'm thinking maybe I need to set the return type to true or false based on the above and see if that works.

Comment: It 's strange. Your code looks fine . I test your code by putting `alert('oncomplete run')` in the oncomplete event , and it runs and the alert is popped up.Do your `reloadConfig()` really completes without any error?

Comment: I'll add the method as an edit

Answer (score 0):

Some addons may compromise the firing of the 'oncomplete' event.
If you are out of options, start disabling some addons to see if it works.
Specifically I had the same problem with Firefox 14.0.1 and Firebug 1.7.3.
Once I disabled Firebug, the 'oncomplete' worked again.